# Uima Ruta Rule for Below Regex

Tags: machine-learning, uima, ruta

I need to annotate below cases. I have block of texts & need to get sub blocks of texts which contains banks.For example below is a complete text block i need to annotate **Bank of America** as Bank Name.

- **hereinafter described and hereinafter referred to as Owner and Bank
  of America  NA,successor in interest from**

There could be many cases for bank name

- **Bank of America [Bank in starting]**
- **Royal Bank of Scotland  [Bank in middle]**
- **Yes Bank [Bank in end]**
  etc.

So text need to be annotate totally depends on bank
I'm not able to write generic rule to cover all cases so far i've tried below rules

```
 - Rule 1



     W[0,3] BankNameKeyWord W[0,3] {-> MARK(BANKNAME,1,3)};(looking around bank for 3 words)

 - Rule 2

       W? W? W? BankNameKeyWord W? W? W? {-> MARK(BANKNAME,1,7)};
```

I'm looking for generic approach to cover all cases.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken; but given that you use the java tag, don't you need to show java code?

Comment: You cannot possibly cover all cases; this problem is not solvable with any form of regex. It requires a natural language processing approach but it will never achieve 100% accuracy.

Comment: @GhostCat added java tag by mistake

Comment: @JimGarrison may be not generic but how can we cover with if else condition?

Comment: just a comment: optional rue elements at the beginning of a rule are not optional if there is no extra starting achor.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe apply a rule like:

```
(CW[0,3] @BankNameKeyWord SW.ct=="of"? CW[0,3]) {-> MARK(BANKNAME,1,3)};
```

but this does not solve your problem. As the commnets note, you need some linguistic preprocessing like a chunker. If it's just bank names, you could consider a dictionary.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*